# Передача замыкания в потоки

Tags: rust, замыкания, анонимная-функция

Требуется передать замыкание в потоки.

Замыкание передается на функцию а дальше раздается 2м и более потокам. Раньше (может и не грамотно, но это работало) оборачивал замыкание в `Arc<Mutex<function>>` но это работает лишь одновременно с 1 потоком.

*Потоки не должны завершатся! Потоки должны работать асинхронно.*

**Пример кода:**

```
use std::sync::Mutex;
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    println!("Start");
    test_thread(
        4,
        move |n| {
            println!("#Ulin Test ok. Thread {}", n);
        }
    );

    thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(1_000));
}


pub fn test_thread<F>(count:u32, function: F) -> bool where F: Fn(usize) + Send + 'static{
    let arc_function = Arc::new(Mutex::new(function));

    for i in 0..count {
        let arc_function_1 = arc_function.clone();
        let n = i as usize;
        thread::spawn(
            move || {
                println!("Thread start {}", &n);
                let arc_function = arc_function_1.lock().unwrap();

                arc_function(n);

                //ПОТОК НЕ ДОЛЖЕН ЗАВЕРШАТСЯ
                loop {
                    thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(3_000));
                }
            }
        );
    }
    true
}
```

**Запуск:** https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=62319cad6b0196a980a2f13aeddab244&version=stable

**Вывод:**

```
Start
Thread start 2
#Ulin Test ok. Thread 2
Thread start 1
Thread start 3
Thread start 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавь `Sync` в необходимые trait замыкания и убери с него оборачивающий `Mutex`. Тогда сможешь использовать замыкание, содержащее только `Sync` переменные, т.е. безопасные для одновременного использования из разных тредов. Те переменные, которые не безопасны, придётся оборачивать в `Mutex`, чтобы получить на них `Sync`.

**Пример кода**:

```
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    println!("Start");
    test_thread(
        4,
        move |n| {
            println!("#Ulin Test ok. Thread {}", n);
            thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(3));
            println!("#Ulin Test second ok. Thread {}", n);
        }
    );

    thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(1_000));
}


pub fn test_thread<F>(count:u32, function: F) -> bool where F: Fn(usize) + Send + Sync + 'static{
    let arc_function = Arc::new(function);

    for i in 0..count {
        let arc_function_1 = arc_function.clone();
        let n = i as usize;
        thread::spawn(
            move || {
                println!("Thread start {}", &n);
                let arc_function = arc_function_1;

                arc_function(n);

                //ПОТОК НЕ ДОЛЖЕН ЗАВЕРШАТСЯ
                loop {
                    thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(3_000));
                }
            }
        );
    }
    true
}
```

**Запуск**: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=92a0e9d4e827e2cf28a331a8a460557e&version=stable

**Вывод**:

```
Start
Thread start 3
#Ulin Test ok. Thread 3
Thread start 1
#Ulin Test ok. Thread 1
Thread start 2
#Ulin Test ok. Thread 2
Thread start 0
#Ulin Test ok. Thread 0
#Ulin Test second ok. Thread 3
#Ulin Test second ok. Thread 1
#Ulin Test second ok. Thread 2
#Ulin Test second ok. Thread 0
```

Comment: Вот так просто:) спасибо!